# Office Communicator Call via RDP?

Tags: remote-desktop, ms-office-communicator

I login to my desktop at work from home via Remote Desktop.  I run Office Communicator on my remote desktop. It works fine except that I cannot make calls.  Is there anyway to get it to put the audio over RDP so I can use my local headset?

Answer (score 3):

The Remote Desktop Connection client allows you to send audio to and from the remote computer. Set this on the Local Resources tab before you connect and it should allow your local speakers and microphone to work for Communicator.

[image: Remote Desktop Connection audio settings]

Comment: My version doesn't have the "Remote Audio Recording" option.  Was this enabled in a newer version of the RDP client?

Comment: Yes. Version 7.0 of the client for Windows XP and Vista can be downloaded here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969084